# quickbooks-ruby how to get list of custom fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks-online

Hi I'm using the quickbooks-ruby gem and want to get the custom fields I  have defined.  The API says that they can be found here: Preferences.SalesFormsPrefs.CustomField

And in this file:
https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/blob/master/lib/quickbooks/model/preferences.rb

I see can see that there is a :custom_fields variable for :sales_forms, but when I get the preferences back, Preferences.sales_forms.custom_fields keeps returning nil.

How do I access this custom_fields variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Preferences.sales_forms.inspect` return what you expect?

Comment: here's what it returns: #<#<Class:0x007faa5b5c6c20> custom_txn_numbers?: true, allow_deposit?: false, allow_discount?: false, default_discount_account?: nil, allow_estimates?: true, estimate_message?: nil, e_transaction_enabled_status?: nil, e_transaction_attach_pdf?: true, e_transaction_payment_enabled?: true, ipn_support_enabled?: false, allow_service_date?: true, allow_shipping?: false, default_shipping_account?: nil, default_terms: 3, default_customer_message: nil>

Comment: As you can see, there is not custom_fields attribute, even though I have custom fields defined in my QBO account and the file above has this defined for sales_forms:  xml_reader :custom_fields, :as => [CustomField], :from => 'CustomField', in: 'CustomField'

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here's the code:

```
@items = service.query("Select * from Preferences")

<%= @items.entries[0].sales_forms.custom_fields %>
```

And make sure you're using version **0.6.7** of the quickbooks-ruby gem *(0.6.6 and prior don't have this implemented)*.